# MATLAB return of vector function with IF statement

Tags: function, matlab, if-statement, vector, return

I am calling a self written function 'func' of a vector like this:

```
x_values=[0 1 2];
result=func(x_values);
```

The problem is that in this function i have an `if` statement to determine the ouput. If I apply this function to a scalar, I have no problem, but if I apply it to a vector of numbers, the `if` statement doesn't do his job. why? And how can i repair it?

```
function [y]=func(x)
if(x==0)
  y=0
else
  y=1./sin(x);
end
end
```

Comment: use size(x) to determine if your input is a scalar or vector before continuing. have u tried debugging your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to treat the zero and non-zero entries separately. This is easily achieved via indexing:

```
function [y]=func(x)
xIsZero = x==0;

%# preassign y
y = x;

%# fill in values for y
y(xIsZero) = 0

y(~xIsZero) = 1./sin(x(~xIsZero))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is explained in the help document of [IF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html):

> An evaluated expression is true when the result is nonempty and
>   contains all nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). Otherwise,
>   the expression is false.

Conclusion: either add a for loop, or find a better way to vectorize your expression

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign only a subset of the vector.  For example:

```
function [y]=func(x)
    y=zeros(size(x));
    mask = x ~= 0;
    y(mask) = 1 ./ sin(x(mask));
end
```

Comment: However, if you're calculating `sinc`, you want to use `ones`, not `zeros`.